# How to use list value in another method?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have few checkBoxes and i am storing user decision in a list and then i need to use it in another method. But if i try to ad List userDecision = new List(); to the method FindAllArticlesForPurchase  the list is empty. How can i get my values so i can filter my articles based on the selection?

```
List<int> userDecision = new List<int>() { -1, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

 public bool FilterAllItems
        {
            set
            {

                _filterAllItems = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
                if (FilterAllItems == true)
                {
                    FilterBeginnerItems = false;
                    FilterIntermediateItems = false;
                    FilterUpperIntermediateItems = false;
                    FilterAdvancedItems = false;
                    userDecision[-1] = -1;
                }


            }
            get => _filterAllItems;
        }

        public bool FilterBeginnerItems
        {
            set
            {
                _filterBeginnerItems = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();

                if (_filterBeginnerItems)
                {
                    FilterAllItems = false;

                    userDecision[1] = 1;
                }

            }
            get => _filterBeginnerItems;
        }

 private static List<Article> FindAllArticlesForPurchase(List<Article> allArticles)
        {
           List<int> userDecision = new List<int>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling List userDecision = new List() you are declaring a new List in the scope of your static method. new List() will always create a new List with no entries at all. Also when leaving the scope of your method, that List will be gone, as it only lives within that method.

Since you want to access the List from a static method, change the Declaration of your List as follows:

```
public static List<int> UserDecision
{
    get { return userDecision; }
    set { userDecision = value; }
}
private static List<int> userDecision = new List<int>() { -1, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Now in your FindAllArticlesForPurchase method (and all the other methods accessing the List), you can simply access it by calling

```
YourClassName.UserDecision
```

Please note that you have to substitute YourClassName to the name of the class which includes this code.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `List<int> userDecision = new List<int>();` you will get indeed an empty list.
In you code, the userDecision list seem to be a property of your class. 
If I'm understanding correctly, if you want to access it into your FindAllArticlesForPurchase method, you should set this method not static

```
private List<Article> FindAllArticlesForPurchase(List<Article> allArticles)
{
   // access userDecision here
}
```

or pass the reference into the method parameters :

```
private List<Article> FindAllArticlesForPurchase(List<Article> allArticles, ref List<int> userDecision)
{
    // access userDecision here
}
```

This way you could call your method with `MyClassInstanciation.FindAllArticlesForPurchase(allArticles)` or `FindAllArticlesForPurchase(allArticles, ref userDecision)`

[EDIT] : I just saw that Markus answered at the same moment. I agree with this answer too. It depends on what you are looking to do exactly and where you are calling this function.

Comment: While we both don't know if that method is really meant to be static, your answer would be correct as well.